# How to check an array for a value? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Im trying to check an array for a value as such. not sure how to go about. If anyone could help that would be great.

```
var array1 = [0];

if (DONT KNOW WHAT TO SAY TO CHECK FOR 0 IN THE ARRAY) {
    Do something
}
```

Comment: It depends on structure of your array!

Comment: You need to tell us what would be sample structures of the array in your context.

Answer (score 0):

simple like this

```
if (array1[0] == "0") {
    //Do something
}
```

and if you have more values in your array you should use `indexOf()`

```
var array1 = [0, 3, 1, 4];
if (array1.indexOf(0) != -1)  {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> DONT KNOW WHAT TO SAY TO CHECK FOR 0 IN THE ARRAY

If you want to check for `0` in the `array1` (anywhere in the array), then use `indexOf`

```
if (array1.indexOf(0) != -1) 
{
    Do something
}
```

Comment: whats the difference between indexOf and contains?

Comment: @HenderikusParekowhai Array doesn't have built-in `contains` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @HenderikusParekowhai Also `contains` may mean that you are looking for  value which has `0` as substring.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the array. If you have no idea what place the array is you need to go through the array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 0) {
       //Do all the things
    }
}
```

Comment: forgot all about indexOf. this is very inefficient so I would say go with those!! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
if(array1.indexOf(0) == 0){
   //Do your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do

```
for(var i in array){
    if(array[i] == 0){
       //Do all the things
    }
}
```